# What will firedancer optimistically enable?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

What are the best case scenarios of firedancer?

I know they have been marketing on test versions 1 million TPS - does that mean cost of transaction and storing data on accounts goes down more?

Also it seems it's good for network stability, but generally curious what the downstream effects of firedancer coming out could be.